# Change value of textbox based on radio box selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the value of a textbox based on the selection a group of 4 radio buttons. This is not the actual html code, but a simplified version:

```
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup" value="5" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup" value="10" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup" value="15" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup" value="20" />

    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
```

So what I am trying to do is fill the textbox named "amount" with either 5, 10, 15 or 20 based on which radio button is selected.

I am new to jquery and everything I tried did not work.

Thank you in advance for any help.

cdr6545

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do this by adding class.

Working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apk68230/)**

**HTML:**

```
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="5" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="10" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="15" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="20" />

    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('.radiogroup').change(function(e){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $('#amount').val(selectedValue)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ID's are unique, and an ID can only be used on one element in the current document, so change it to classes.

Then attach a `change` event handler to the radios, get the checked one, and set the value of the text input to the checked radios value

```js
$('.radiogroup').on('change', function() {
  $('#amount').val( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="5" />
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="10" />
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="15" />
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="20" />
<br /><br />
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('input[name="radiogroup"]').click(function()
{
    $('#amount').val($(this).val())
})
```